# systemd-sysusers.service Unit fails to start on a VPS

Tags: linux, debian, systemd

I am trying to troubleshoot my `systemd-sysusers.service` but I don't know where to start.
First off a bit of background this is running `Debian 10` on a VPS which uses `Solaris VM` among other technology

The unit is failing to start due to

```
? systemd-sysusers.service - Create System Users                                                                                             
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-sysusers.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)                                             
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-08-05 08:39:41 EDT; 3s ago                                                              
     Docs: man:sysusers.d(5)                                                                                                                 
           man:systemd-sysusers.service(8)                                                                                                   
  Process: 29802 ExecStart=/bin/systemd-sysusers (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)                                                             
 Main PID: 29802 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                             
Aug 05 08:39:41 myvps systemd-sysusers[29802]: Creating group floppy with gid 25.                                                  
Aug 05 08:39:41 myvps systemd-sysusers[29802]: Creating group audio with gid 29.                                                   
Aug 05 08:39:41 myvps systemd-sysusers[29802]: Creating group dip with gid 30.                                                     
Aug 05 08:39:41 myvps systemd-sysusers[29802]: Creating group video with gid 44.                                                   
Aug 05 08:39:41 myvps systemd-sysusers[29802]: Creating group plugdev with gid 46.                                                 
Aug 05 08:39:41 myvps systemd-sysusers[29802]: /etc/gshadow: Group "cdrom" already exists.                                         
Aug 05 08:39:41 myvps systemd-sysusers[29802]: Failed to write files: File exists                                                  
Aug 05 08:39:41 myvps systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE                     
Aug 05 08:39:41 myvps systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.                                        
Aug 05 08:39:41 myvps systemd[1]: Failed to start Create System Users.
```

The fact is that if I check `sudo vi /etc/gshadow` I just get a line regarding to cdrom

```
cdrom:*::debianuser
```

But Despite that I don't really have a clue on how to continue

Comment: Does the same group exist in `/etc/group`? And does the journal contain _other_ error messages from the service? Your "status" output only shows the last 10 lines, not the whole thing.

Comment: The log is not complete but it only has one more message showing a initialization process (not error) , I don't have that group on `/etc/group` I reckon I have to add it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

systemd-sysusers expects the /etc/passwd & /etc/shadow, and similarly /etc/group & /etc/gshadow, files to be in sync with each other. If a group is missing, then it should be missing from *both* of those files. So when sysusers is adding a group that "doesn't exist" but finds it already present in /etc/gshadow, it reports this as an error.

Either manually add the group with `groupadd` so that it exists in both files, or manually *remove* it from /etc/gshadow so that systemd-sysusers will be able to properly re-add it, or use `grpck` to automatically fix all inconsistencies across both files.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , so sorted it thanks to the response of @user1686
Basically and for some reason , my `/etc/gshadow` file differed from `/etc/group` in some lines . Some Groups seems the be in the former and not on the latter , in my case this were the lines:
`sudo vi /etc/gshadow`

```
cdrom:*::debianuser
floppy:*::debianuser
audio:*::debianuser
dip:*::debianuser
video:*::debianuser
plugdev:*::debianuser
```

I just needed to create them manually to sort the problem

```
sudo groupadd cdrom
sudo groupadd floppy
(...)
```